# Partial System Restore

Tags: windows-8, backup

Very basic question I guess but I'm finding conflicting information on the web so I just want to make completely sure. I'm doing a restore of my system and my understanding is that the only way I can keep my application/software is by using a System Image. My understanding is also that I cannot select which parts of the system Image I restore and have to restore the whole system. I was hoping that I could create a backup, including my applications/software, and then pick and choose what I restore later. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Use any drive imaging program, you'll be able to restore your system to its previous state in under an hour.

Comment: @gronostaj Sorry I just updated my question.

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: Your user data of course can be restored piecemeal, but not programs.